# How to insert all the values from Listbox to datagridview in c#

Tags: c#

i was trying to save all the values/text(not the selected one but all of the values on it) in the listbox to datagridview

like this: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEdFW.png)

here's my code in saving to datagridview

```
Data.con.Open();



string SaveStr = "Insert into tblOrder (CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerAdd, Date, Orders, TotalPrice) Values (@CustomerID, @CustomerName, @CustomerAdd, @Date, @Orders, @TotalPrice)";
SqlCommand SaveCmd = new SqlCommand(SaveStr, Data.con);

SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", textBox4.Text);
SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", textBox5.Text);
SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerAdd", textBox6.Text);
SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateTimePicker1.Value);
SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Orders", listBox1.Items.ToString());
SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TotalPrice", textBox3.Text);

SaveCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Data.con.Close();
LoadData();
```

and the output is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCEYd.png)

THanks in advance

Comment: what is the column type in DB where you want to save all listitemvalue ?

Comment: what you can do is to create a comma separated string and pass that in parameter this way you can save it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListBox.Items enables you to obtain a reference to the list of items that are currently stored in the ListBox. With this reference you can obtain a count of the items in the collection. Any task can be performed with the item collection. But since you want the string to be stored to the DataBase. This might do the trick for you.

```
String.Join("," , listBox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray());
```

Comment: Pleasure @sakusa1 Happy Coding ahead :)

Answer (score -2):

what you can do is to create a comma separated string and pass that in parameter this way you can save it . below is the updated complete code .

```
        Data.con.Open();



    string SaveStr = "Insert into tblOrder (CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerAdd, Date, Orders, TotalPrice) Values (@CustomerID, @CustomerName, @CustomerAdd, @Date, @Orders, @TotalPrice)";
    SqlCommand SaveCmd = new SqlCommand(SaveStr, Data.con);

    SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", textBox4.Text);
    SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", textBox5.Text);
    SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerAdd", textBox6.Text);
    SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateTimePicker1.Value);
    SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Orders", String.Join("," , listBox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray());
     ));
    SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TotalPrice", textBox3.Text);

    SaveCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Data.con.Close();
    LoadData();
```

Comment: How is it different from my answer??

Comment: its same @MohitShrivastava I just posted it after you .I was not that fast as you were .

Comment: @MohitShrivastava if you read my comments above . you will notice that I already answered before you in my commnets I  suggest to have a comma separated list . Then I posted the whole solution as an answer . So to me your answer is same as mine so you should remove that not me besides you can check the timings as well if you like to .

Comment: Even I wrote the answer before your comment. Your comment is 1 min later than my answer. See it yourself.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava you are right. You answered first